# "Could not initialize class" error running lint target from gradle

Tags: android, gradle, gradlew

I'm working on an Android project with two projects inside it. When trying to run a build with gradlew (`./gradlew build`), I see the following error:

> Execution failed for task ':example:lint'.
>
> Could not initialize class
>   com.android.build.gradle.tasks.Lint$LintGradleIssueRegistry

With stacktrace enabled, this is listed as a `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError`.

Oddly, the first time I ran this (which downloaded dependencies), the build failed with a different error:

> Execution failed for task ':example:lint'.
>
> lombok/ast/Node

The gradle wrapper that Android SDK created for the project is using Gradle 2.8.

Could this be a configuration issue with the project or my dev machine? I'm trying to avoid using the Android SDK `lint` tool as this complains about the projects using Gradle (and I hear it may miss some parts of these projects).

Comment: As an update, I see the same error(s) with Gradle 2.11.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turned out this was a configuration issue in our build.gradle. The following line had been added for testing and never removed:

```
configurations.classpath.exclude group: 'com.android.tools.external.lombok'
```

As such, the classes needed for linting were missing.

The following discussion pointed us in the right direction, in case it's useful to anyone else:

https://github.com/evant/gradle-retrolambda/issues/96